# Solve Rational Equation for Root Music in MATLAB

Tags: polynomials, rootfinding

I'm trying to estimate DOA in the Hybrid architecture using root music so I need to solve the attached equation to find the roots for the Root_Music equation in Matlab. Does anyone have an idea for solving this?

$$f_\theta(\theta)=g^H(\theta)\mathbf{a}^H_{M}(\theta)\mathbf{E}_{N}\mathbf{E}^H_{N}\mathbf{a}_{M}g^H(\theta)=0$$

$$g(\theta)=\frac{1-\exp^{j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} M d\sin({\theta})}}{1-\exp^{j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}d\sin({\theta})}}$$

$$\mathbf{a}_{M}=[1,\exp^{j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} M d\sin({\theta})},.......,\exp^{j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} (K-1)M d\sin({\theta})}]$$

$$f_\theta(\theta)=\frac{2-\exp^{-j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} M d\sin({\theta})}-\exp^{j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} M d\sin({\theta})}}{2-\exp^{-j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}d\sin({\theta})}-\exp^{j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}d\sin({\theta})}}\sum_{m=1}^K\sum_{n=1}^K\exp^{-j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} (m-1)d\sin({\theta})}\mathbf{C}_{mn}\exp^{j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(n-1)d\sin({\theta})}=0$$

$K$ is the number of subarrays, $M$ is the number of elements in each subarray, $d$ is the antenna elements separation and we decompose covaiance matrix of the received signal into signal subspace and noise subspace $\mathbf{E}^H_{N} $
$$z=\exp^{j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} M d\sin({\theta})}$$

$$\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{E}_{N}\mathbf{E}^H_{N}$$

$$f_z(z)=\frac{2-z^{-1}-z}{2-z^{\frac{-1}{M}}-z^{\frac{1}{M}}}\sum_{m=1}^K\sum_{n=1}^Kz^{-(m-1)}\mathbf{C}_{mn}z^{(n-1)}=0$$

so I need to get the $2K-2$ roots of this equation to estimate $\theta$

i solved the second part only using:
$$\sum_{m=1}^K\sum_{n=1}^K\exp^{-j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} (m-1)d\sin({\theta})}\mathbf{C}_{mn}\exp^{j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(n-1)d\sin({\theta})}=\sum_{l=-K+1}^{K-1}\mathbf{C}_{l}z^l=0$$
where $\mathbf{C}_{l}$ is the sum of the elements along the lth diagonal of $\mathbf{C}$

is it possible to consider only the roots of the second part??